# WordPress get post format archive link

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, custom-wordpress-pages, post-format

I want to get the archive of a category based on a post format (example: video post format)
I tried to get a sample URL using this function: [get_post_type_archive_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/)

But I couldn't get the link and I got false for returning that
How can I get some example links for archive of specified post format in a category?

Can you please let me know how is a sample link of a custom post format for a category ?

I put this line in index.php of theme:

```
var_dump( get_post_type_archive_link('video') );
```

Created a video post type, but nothing display for that value! just false

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show me your code ?

Comment: I put this on my index of theme, Tried to browse many posts and pages which it may be return something, But just false: var_dump( get_post_type_archive_link('video') );

Comment: it will return false if post_type does not exist or post_type has no archive.

Comment: @VidyaAnand No, I tried for that , But nothing returned, just false

Comment: @VidyaAnand Can you please tell me a sample url of an archive post type? How should it be ? something like url.com/category/?post_type=video ?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'video' ); ?>">videos</a>, if you have pretty permalinks enabled, the url will be like http://your-site.com/video/

Comment: @VidyaAnand I get 404 for this, But I have many video post types, and also my permalinks are OK

Comment: @VidyaAnand Hey , I found the problem and solution, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38741566/wordpress-get-post-type-archive-link/38743859#38743859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finding a way to list all POST FORMATS in a category, Post type is something else

**Core WordPress post types are:**

1. **Post** (Post Type: 'post')
2. **Page** (Post Type: 'page')
3. **Attachment** (Post Type: 'attachment')
4. **Revision** (Post Type: 'revision')
5. **Navigation menu** (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')

**WordPress Post Formats:**

1. **aside** - Typically styled without a title. Similar to a Facebook note update.
2. **gallery** - A gallery of images. Post will likely contain a gallery shortcode and will have image attachments.
3. **link** - A link to another site. Themes may wish to use the first  tag in the post content as the external link for that post. An alternative approach could be if the post consists only of a URL, then that will be the URL and the title (post_title) will be the name attached to the anchor for it.
4. **image** - A single image. The first  tag in the post could be considered the image. Alternatively, if the post consists only of a URL, that will be the image URL and the title of the post (post_title) will be the title attribute for the image.
5. **quote** - A quotation. Probably will contain a blockquote holding the quote content. Alternatively, the quote may be just the content, with the source/author being the title.
6. **status** - A short status update, similar to a Twitter status update.
7. **video** - A single video or video playlist. The first  tag or object/embed in the post content could be considered the video. Alternatively, if the post consists only of a URL, that will be the video URL. May also contain the video as an attachment to the post, if video support is enabled on the blog (like via a plugin).
8. **audio** - An audio file or playlist. Could be used for Podcasting.
9. **chat** - A chat transcript, like so:

To list the archive of a post format we can use something like this:
http://sitename.com/type/image